In vs code my laravel all project directory is not showing

I want to show to all the laravel folder structure will show. At the left it is only showing the files which are open. I am unable to work on my projects.

In vscode, in front of EXPLORER: OPEN EDITORS click on 3 dots and uncheck Open Editors & check folders

Nice beat me to it.

You need to click '...' button in the explorer and check folders and uncheck Open Editors
